# How do store API response into object so I can use it later in script?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am using the Yelp API to get info on businesses. I plan to eventually map the response. So I need to store it somewhere in my script in order to access the lat/long

My Ajax request has worked judging by console.log of response. I cant seem to do the next step where I store yelp response into either a JSON or GeoJSON

```js
$.ajax("/yelp", {
  data: {
   term: searchEstablishment,
   location: selectedGeography
  },
  //this works:
  success: function(response) {
   console.log(response)

  },
```

Comment: How about placing a variable outside your $.ajax() function, then set that variable to be the content of the data? Then once it has succeeded, you can call another function and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not necessarily trying to put my results on the webpage as part of any list. I am trying to just store them and then use a leaflet plug in to map them. So would I need the last JQuery?